# Ext.form.field.Time commits as Date-Time value

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an `Ext.form.field.Time` editor on my screen. I would like it to represent only time values, not date-time. I know that it is still an Ext.form.field.Date behind the scenes and the editor ignores the date part. But I want it also to commit as a time to the server. For this purpose I set the property `submitFormat: 'H:i'`. But for an input of `02:00`, extjs still sends down the response as `2008-01-01T02:00:00`. Any ideas on how to make it commit with the time portion only? Thanks.

(I am on Extjs 4.2.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/cr9) here and it seems like it is working correctly. I've also tried calling form.submit() and the form data shows up correctly as well. How are you getting the data? Are you calling `timefield.getValue()` instead of `timefield.getSubmitValue()`? That seems to return the full date string.